# How to convert substrb in Oracle to Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Oracle: `select substrb('よろしくお願いいたします',2,3) from dual;`
Result: `ろ`

How to convert to Postgresql?

Comment: `substr('よろしくお願いいたします',2,1)` should do that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm converting from oracle database to postgre database. I have a problem as bellow. In oracle database using function substrb to returns a portion of string, beginning at a specified byte position, and a specified number of bytes long. Example select substrb(account_name,1,2) from account; But i don't find substrb in postgresql. Everyone can help me convert it or write function in postgresql to convert it. Thanks a lot

Comment: First: it's Postgres or PostgreSQL, not "postgre". Secondly if you want the 2 _character_ from that string then use `substr('よろしくお願いいたします',2,1)` - that returns **exactly** what you asked for in your question ( `ろ`). Why do you think you need to count bytes?

Comment: What is the result of `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'` in your Oracle DB? Add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

With byte, in postgresql you can change it to bytea then extract the bytes:

```
select convert_from(substring('よろしくお願いいたします'::bytea,4,3),'UTF8');
```

The Substring(bytea [from int] [for int] ) will get the sub-bytea from input. Then you can convert it into UTF-8. 
Reference more: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html

You can try this for extract with character:

```
select substring('よろしくお願いいたします',2,1)
```

Get String at location '2' for '1' character(s)

Reference document: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: I want calculates lengths using bytes not character(s)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand much. It give the same result you want.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hopely it will satisfy you.

Comment: Thanks for help. But in Oracle, select substrb('よろしくお願いいたします',4,3) from dual; result => "し". Your answer, result => "ろ"

Comment: In oracle and postgre, the parameter must be the same. Thanks

Comment: @thvinh According to the example in your question `よ` have length 1 byte (because next character starts at the 2nd byte) and `ろ` have length 3 bytes. And according to your comment `し` starts at the 4th bytes (last byte of the `ろ` because 1+3=4). What encoding do you using in the Oracle???

Comment: @ Abelisto: all character in 'よろしくお願いいたします' are 2 byte

Comment: @thvinh So why do you select 3 bytes to get single character?

Comment: @ Abelisto: I want create new function `substrb` in Postgresql same `substrb` in Oracle.

Comment: I'm converting from oracle database to postgre database. I have a problem as bellow. 
In oracle database using function substrb to returns a portion of string, beginning at a specified byte position, and a specified number of bytes long. 
Example select substrb(account_name,1,2) from account; 

But i don't find substrb in postgresql. Everyone can help me convert it or write function in postgresql to convert it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yay, I understand your requirement. The issue here, I think is the encoding. Which encoding you are in.
When we are in UTF-8, all those character is 3 bytes. You can check it by calling this query `select s, octet_length(s) FROM unnest(string_to_array('よろしくお願いいたします', NULL)) d(s)`.
Others, when I copy your text from web, it also is UTF-8.